# sum + Integral involving dirac delta function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, constraint

I am trying to evaluate something along the lines of

$$\sum_{n=0}^{10} \,\int\,dx\, x^2 \delta(x-n)$$

using `NINtegrate[]` and `NSum[]`.

I am quite new to this. I used the following:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] = x - n

NSum[NIntegrate[x^2DiracDelta[f], {x, 0, 100}], {n, 0, 10}]
```

If I do this I get an error message saying

> Integrand is not numerical at points 0-100.

How to go about this? Thanks!

Edit: Please note that the while this example can be tackled without using `Integrate[]` (as has been pointed out below), I need to learn how to do this using numerical techniques.

Comment: Welcome. It is recommended that you format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is suggested that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site).

Comment: `DiracDelta` is a generalized function and isn't numeric, so you cannot use numerical integration with it. If you would state your actual problem, perhaps we can suggest another approach.

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious that it makes no sense to try to do numerical computations with a Dirac delta function!  It is not even a function in the mathematical sense.  Just think abut what "values" a Dirac delta takes and think about how numerical integration works. This is a very good example of why it is necessary to understand what various numerical methods do and why it is necessary to learn how to implement them even though we have so many software packages that provide them out of the box.

Comment: @JohnDoty you are right of course. My actual problem involves a functions like MathieuCPrime ans MathieuS which are not known analytically. I will post it un another question.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for numeric techniques, this can be done analytically

```
Sum[
 Integrate[x^2 DiracDelta[x - n], {x, 0, 100}],
 {n, 0, 10}]

(*  385  *)
```

Since

```
Assuming[Element[n, Reals],
 Integrate[g[x] DiracDelta[x - n], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]

(*  g[n]  *)
```

The original `Sum` of the integrals is equivalent to

```
Sum[n^2, {n, 0, 10}]

(*  385  *)
```

**EDIT:**  Numerically integrating a [`DiracDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html) doesn't seem reasonable since you are unlikely to sample at the essential value.

Your integral is basically just

```
Clear[f]

f[n_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{n^2, 0 <= n <= 100}}]
```

Note use of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) rather than [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) when using [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) although its use is unnecessary here

And the `Sum` is

```
Sum[f[n], {n, 0, 10}]

(*  385  *)
```

Or using `NSum`

```
NSum[f[n], {n, 0, 10}]

(*  385.  *)
```

Comment: Thanks. But this simple example was for the purpose of demonstration. I need to know how to do this when NIntegrate and NSum are necessary.

Comment: I should have made that clear in the question. Added an edit.